# AWS Amplify Authentication sign in multiple times with same email

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-amplify

I'm implementing authentication for a mobile application. The sign in fields are username, email, and password. After a user has made an account with one email, they can come back and make another account with the same email but different username and password.
Is there a simple work around solution to return an error for this scenario? It seems like a common problem but I cant seem to find an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Only "easy" solution for now is to switch to login with email.